# How find this minimum of the $|PA_{1}|+|PA_{2}|+|PA_{3}|+\cdots+|PA_{n}|$

Tags: geometry, inequality

**Question:**

> give the $n$ point $$A_{1}(x_{1},y_{1}),A_{2}(x_{2},y_{2}),A_{3}(x_{3},y_{3}),A_{4}(x_{4},y_{4}),\cdots,A_{n}(x_{n},y_{n}),x_{i}\in R,y_{i}>0$$

Find a ponit $P(x,0)$,such
$$(|PA_{1}|+|PA_{2}|+|PA_{3}|+\cdots+|PA_{n}|)_{]min}$$

[image]

for the $n=2$, It is very  famous problem,

see this follow 
$$|PA_{1}|+|PA_{2}|\ge |PA'_{1}|$$
so
$$(|PA_{1}|+|PA_{2}|)_{\min}=\sqrt{(x_{1}-x_{2})^2+(y_{1}+y_{2})^2}$$
if and only if $$P(x_{2}-\dfrac{x_{2}(x_{2}-x_{1})}{y_{1}+y_{2}},0)$$

[image]

I think this is also famous problem? can you someone know it? Thank you

Comment: If we try solving this for only three points in the specific case that $A_1 = (-1,1)$, $A_2 = (1,1)$ and $A_3 = (2,2)$, then the solution for $x$ is a root of a $12$-th degree polynomial (see [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Bderivative+sqrt%28%28x%2B1%29%5E2%2B1%5E2%29%2Bsqrt%28%28x-1%29%5E2%2B1%5E2%29%2Bsqrt%28%28x-2%29%5E2%2B2%5E2%29%5D+%3D+0)). This suggests that a nice closed formula isn't possible.

Comment: This is called by some people as the [n-ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ellipse). Please see the referenced papers therein.